# Executing rel="prefetch" resources onload

Tags: javascript, html, performance, preload, prefetch

I'm trying to figure out how to force rel=prefetch to happen after window.onload.

I know that this is browser dependent but at the moment Chrome and Opera is reported to download these resources in parallel.

**Will appending a link to the head after the page loads still fire a prefetch correctly and is this the best way to force the prefetch after window.onload?**

```
window.onload( function(){
      var postfetch = document.createElement('/js/future-resource.js');
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(postfetch);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Safari and Opera do not support the rel=prefetch tag.

It will work in Chrome and other browsers. No JavaScript is needed. You can verify that it has worked in chrome by using developer tools, clicking sources and then looking in the folder called "other", which should have the names of the prefetched resources.